# How do I filter the Model based on the value of a textbox using Javascript (Razor)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

this question may be totally non-sense but I am new in MVC and Razor.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. I have a simple table "Products" from where I retrrieve all the
   values using my model. The products table has a field Id, Name,
   Price and StartDate.
2. I am passing the data from the Controller to
       the view as a List
3. In the view I have an AutoComplete field (KendoUI) where I type the
   name of the product
4. In the event handler
       of the AutoCoplete change event, I want to retrieve the "Price" of
       the product that has been typed in the AutoComplete textbox

Below is the code for the Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime FirstRelease { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetsDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The code for my View (partial code) is below:

```
<div id="auto">
    <p>Start typing</p>
    <label for="productAutoComplete">Please select procuct:</label> 
    @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
        .Name("productAutoComplete")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .BindTo(Model)
        .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
        .Placeholder("Select the product")
        .HighlightFirst(true)
        .Suggest(true)
    )

   <script>
       function productAutoComplete_change() {
           var gauge = $("#linearGauge").data("kendoLinearGauge");
           @foreach (var p in Model)  <==== HERE I WANT TO DO THE FILTERING   
           {
               @: gauge.value(@p.Price);
           }                      
       }

       $("#productAutoComplete").bind("change", productAutoComplete_change);

   </script>
</div>
```

*CONCERN FOR VALIDATION:* If I understand the basics of MVC and Razor well, then am I correct to think that the view is rendered once (during the HTTP GET) and therefore I am not able to dynamically filter the Model in Razor (but only in Javascript)? If yes, then what is the right way to do it?

Thank you in advance

Lefteris

Comment: Look here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/autocomplete/overview and here http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource if you want to use ServerFiltering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am I correct to think that the view is rendered once (during the HTTP
>   GET) and therefore I am not able to dynamically filter the Model in
>   Razor (but only in Javascript)?

Yes, that's correct.

> If yes, then what is the right way to do it?

You could use AJAX. For example in the `productAutoComplete_change` function you could send an AJAX request to a controller action that will perform the filtering and return a partial view containing the filtered results.

There are many tutorials out there about using AJAX with ASP.NET MVC. For example with jQuery you could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I was hoping that since I already have performed the lookup in my database once (in order to build the dictionary for the autocomplete) I could avoid doing it again (through the ajax call)